# React testing the Google sign-in button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

How to go about testing the Google sign-in button from Google identity services?

Currently the button is not being found when I run a findBy query. Do I need to mock the API call to Google?

The function that returns the button:

```
export const initialiseGoogle = (callbackResponse, google) => {
 /* global google */
 google.accounts.id.initialize({
   client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_ID,
   callback: callbackResponse,
 });
 window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
   document.getElementsByClassName("buttonSignIn")[0],
  {
    shape: "circle",
    size: "medium",
    type: "standard",
  }
 );
};
```

The useEffect that calls the function:

```
  useEffect(() => {
// Initializes the google sign-in button

  if (google && divRef.current) {
    console.log(google);
    initialiseGoogle(handleCallbackResponse, google);
  }
 }, [google, divRef.current]);
```

The div that takes the button:

```
 <section>
   <div
     ref={divRef}
     className={`buttonSignIn ${signInButtonClass}`}
     hidden={!isSignedIn ? false : true}
   ></div>
 </section>
```

The test and the console during test:

```
 const user = userEvent.setup();

 test("The Google sign-in should be visible within 3sec of page load", async () => {
   const { debug, getByPlaceholderText, getByRole, findByTitle } = customRender(
     Wrapper,
     <App />
     );

   const button = await findByTitle("Sign in with Google Button");

   debug();
  });
```

Test fail:

```
FAIL src/components/__tests__/Header.test.js
 × The Google sign-in should be visible within 3sec of page load (1060 ms)

 ● The Google sign-in should be visible within 3sec of page load

  Unable to find an element with the title: Sign in with Google Button.

Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
<body>
  <div>
    <header>
      <div
        class="w-100 divider-1"
      />
      <div
        class="header-container border-ani container-fluid"
      >
        <div
          class="d-flex full-logo flex-row justify-content-center"
        >
          <i
            class="check square logo-icon outline icon mb-2 "
          />
        </div>
        <div
          class="signIn-div d-flex justify-content-center"
        >
          <section
            class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center"
          >
            <div
              class="buttonSignIn"
            />
       </header>
      </div>
    </body>
```